# Since when has Date & Time been embedded inside a HTTP UserAgent?

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse, user-agent, browser-detection

I'm referring to items like this (I've made the date-time part **Bold**):

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
>   **2013-07-28 09:18:59**

There is more where that came from, the links below point to those useragents occuring back to back (probably from the same person).

http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/details/1324078/index.html
http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/details/1324077/index.html
http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/details/1324073/index.html
http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/details/1324072/index.html

I'm curious, since when has this been happening and/or what software product is doing this? I doubt the HTTP specification has changed, and wondering if the new version of FireFox is doing this (and why) or if it's just an obscure plugin?

**UPDATE:**

If you search for "`2013-0`" you get about 3 different types of UA's that list date/time, here it is:

http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/listings.asp?search=2013-0

On the top of the search results, you get sometime commonly labeled as `GM UserLogonTimeUTC`, after this (if you scroll down the search results), something that seems to be tied to `Windows NT 5.1; Gecko/20100101; FireFox/16.0`, and if you scroll down further, you'll see (once again) date/time UA's that seem to be tied to `Windows NT 5.1; pl; Gecko/20101203; Firefox/3.6.13`! In addition, there seems to be a handful of entries (if you scroll down further) tied to the label `dwb/commit`, whatever that is. But keep in mind, this is just encapsulating the date range of Jan 2013 to Sep 2013, since our search terms begins with "2013-0"

So, three types of UA's that list date/time. Do any of you think this is something we need to worry about or is it just obscure software doing obscure things that we probably don't need to worry about?

Comment: For what it's worth, my Firefox (up to date, Windows 7) reports itself as `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0`.

Comment: @RichieHindle Thanks for the input. I've expanded my search and included interesting information in an UPDATE to my original post. You might find it interesting.

Comment: It's a big old internet, isn't it?  You turn over a stone and all sorts of wiggly things turn up.  As for worrying about it, no, I wouldn't.  Why worry about something beyond your control?

Comment: @RichieHindle I think you are right, I don't see the HTTP Spec changing and every software reporting date/time with their UA's so its all good. Statistically, unlikely and unexpected things are bound to happen as you mentioned :).